# BEM: What are modifiers allowed to modify?

Tags: css, bem

Let's say I have the following CSS for a generic list component, using BEM and SCSS:

```
.list {
  &__item {
    &:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: .3em;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add a modifier that can make the list vertical, like so:

```
.list--vertical {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

My problem arises when I think about the margin for **list__item** elements. For vertical lists, I want my margin on the bottom, not right of each item. If I understood BEM correctly, I cannot modify the style of **list__item** based on the modifer of **list**, is that correct?

To be more precise, this is what I want to do:

```
.list--vertical {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  .list__item {
    &:not(:last-child) {
      margin-bottom: .3em;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

What is the accepted way of dealing with this using BEM? Another modifier for **list__item** that handles the margin? Another block entirely for vertical lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the accepted way of dealing with this using BEM?

Depends on what version of BEM you're using. I use [a variant of the pre-spec concept of BEM](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/), which means that you'll have different answers if you follow [bem.info](http://bem.info).

---

Modifiers should be attached to the element they modify. Modifying a block, however, allows the modifier to be inherited by child elements:

```
<div class="foo foo--example">
  <div class="foo__bar foo--example__bar">...</div>
<div>
```

This gets messy when child elements have modifiers as well:

```
<div class="foo foo--example">
  <div class="
    foo__bar
    foo--example__bar
    foo__bar--another-example
    foo--example__bar--another-example">...</div>
<div>
```

This form of BEM syntax is quite verbose. It's best used on generated code.

---

I use LESS for CSS preprocessing, so my BEM code often looks like:

```
.foo {
  ...

  &__bar {
    ...
  }
}
```

With modifiers it becomes:

```
.foo {
  ...

  &__bar {
    ...
  }

  &--example {
    ...

    &__bar {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

This enforces that the cascade is in the proper order and that all selectors continue to have exactly one class.

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure: you would consider the last example code I posted "valid"?

Comment: @Malax, using a descendant selector is *valid*, but I definitely recommend avoiding them whenever possible. Sometimes it's just a heck of a lot faster to avoid adding the extra modifier classes to each and every individual child element. But I've had situations that it came back to bite me later. Because LESS and Sass make inheritance so much simpler, consider whether you want to have a `vertical-list` block and a `horizontal-list` block that each inherit from a base `list` block.